# How to Use a parameter in Matlab Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to include a parameter in Simulink.

For example, like the block in the picture. How to use a parameter in the gain and get the output which is L*(input), [image]which 'L' is only a parameter, like 'sym L' defined in the Matlab script. Don't have a specific value.

I am asking because I want to get the system transfer function using the model built by Simulink. The model in Simulink has some parameters but doesn't have real value. the final answer should be something Like $$\frac{L_1}{s+L_2}$$

Comment: You cannot use symbolic variables in Simulink, you have to assign a value to your variable L.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the parameter (gain in your case) comes from.
If it is a constant/arbitrary signal, then use multiplication instead of gain.
If it comes from another SimuLink model, then include it as subsystem, where you may define input and outport ports.
If you want to start your model from MatLab, then pass parameters as arguments to the `sim` command, or more generally use [workspace variables](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-edit-and-manage-workspace-variables.html).